# Accessing Objective-c base class's instance variables from a Swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Having an Objective c base class:

```
@interface ObjcClass : NSObject {
    NSString *aVariable_;
}
```

And a swift sub-class:

```
class SwiftClass : ObjcClass {
    func init() {
        // aVariable_ can't be accessed here. An Objective-c derived
        // class has direct access to it's super's instance variables!
    }
}
```

How do I access `ObjcClass` `aVariable_` from within `SwiftClass`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Great query. We have tried to hard to get this done. The only working solution I found

get value by using `self.valueForKey("aVariable_")`

set value using `self.setValue("New Value", forKey: "aVariable_")`

Hope that helps. Possible solution without altering super class.

Comment: That's what I did. I like @JasonTyler's answer though.

Comment: Thanks @Narendra For me I prefer this way with if let var aVar = self.valueForKey("aVariable_") as if your code is in Swift and you use an Objective C library that you can't modify. Works great.

Comment: This is the easiest way, even it's lake of type checking.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find a "proper" way to do this, but I needed badly for it to work. My solution was to create a simple getter method in my Objective C superclass, like this:

**header file**

```
@interface ObjcClass : NSObject {
    NSString *myVariable;
}
- (NSString *)myVariable;
```

**in the implementation file**

```
- (NSString *)myVariable {
    return myVariable;
}
```

I'd love to hear of a better way of doing it, but this at least works.

Comment: I would suggest the noun form `- (NSString *)myVariable`. Per convention, the “get” prefix is typically used when results are returned by reference (e.g. `NSArray`’s `- (void)getObjects:(id[])buffer range:(NSRange)range`). Better still, use a property as other answers suggests.

Answer (score 4):

I've searched a lot for this.
Eventually I changed my code from:

```
@interface PrjRec : NSObject {
    @public
    NSString* name;
}
@end
```

To:

```
@interface PrjRec : NSObject {
}

@property NSString* name;

@end
```

similar to @JasonTyler solution.
Then I can access to my object property from Swift code with simple dot notation `<object instance>.name`,

But I needed to change all existing objective-c references from

```
<object instance>->name
```

To:

```
<object instance>.name
```

or

```
_name
```

if inside class unit.

I hope for a better solution too.

Answer (score 1):

This worked as a pretty neat solution for me, just adding a Swift variable like:

```
var myInstanceVar: String {
    return self.value(forKey: "myInstanceVar") as! String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to have a property, then you can create the property to fit your needs.

```
@interface ObjcClass : NSObject {
    NSString *aVariable_;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSString *aVariable_;
```

...

```
@implementation ObjcClass

@synthesize aVariable_ = aVariable_;
```

This allows the variable to be accessed as `inst->aVariable_` or as `inst.aVariable_`. In the Objective C class the variable can be accessed as `aVariable_` or `self.aVariable_`.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously don't know why anyone does instance variables anymore (for one, they're private by default) vs properties. See Giorgio Calzolato's answer on this (apart from his last line about looking for a better solution - that IS the best solution :) ).

In my case I already had a property and was extra perplexed over why it didn't work. But I realized that the property had a custom time and it needed to be added into my **SDK-Bridging-Header.h** file.

So if your property is set to a custom type like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SDKMyCustomObject *customObject;
```

...then remember to add it to the bridging header.