# swift call superclass objective-c class's member variable

Tags: objective-c, swift

Swift call superclass objective-c class's member variable.
Like this :

```
@interface person: NSObject
{
     NSString *name;
}

@end

// oc
@interface A : person

@end

// swift
class B : person {

}
```

If I want to use the person's name, oc we could `[A new]->name`.
how to use (name) the member variable in swift?

Comment: Why don't you make `name` as a property?

Comment: @trungduc If I do that, there are too many codes to change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Objective-c base class's instance variables from a Swift class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082999/accessing-objective-c-base-classs-instance-variables-from-a-swift-class)

Comment: @trungduc thank u :)