# How to access private variable in swift child class from objective-c superclass?

Tags: swift, inheritance, private, kvc

I have project written in Swift, inside project I have pod written in objective-C. 
I inherited from objective-C framework and make swift file. This objective-C framework has many classes with many private properties which I need to access and edit them. Framework in pods so I can't edit it directly.
Any way how I can do it? With KVC or Swizzle anything ?

Comment: I think this may this help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082999/accessing-objective-c-base-classs-instance-variables-from-a-swift-class

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

Are you sure that you can not edit Pod script ? May be it's lock and the only thing you have to do is unlock the script and switch private variables to public (or delete the 'private' because in swift the variables are automatically public)

**Second solution**
You can use protocol to access to this variables

I found for you a perfect tutorial [Protocol/Delegate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBWu6TnhLeY)

**Third solution**

USE IT ONLY IF YOU HAVE NO IDEA:
Use global variable, but it's not recommended to use this method.
So if nobody here give you a better idea and you are stuck on this problem, use them until you find a better solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately i have to let pods lock because of new versions of framework. Can you little bit explain how I can do it with global variable ?