# How to refer to objective c instance variable in Swift subclass?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a hierarchy of extended objective c classes.
Then I created a swift class that extends an objective c class.
In the bridging header file I added the parent class (it is Objective c). So the inheritance is ok, but I cannot access the super class properties.

```
@interface ObjectivecViewController : ExtendedUIViewController
 {   
     IBOutlet UIView *view1;
 }
//----------------------------------------
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SwiftViewController : ObjectivecViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view1 -----> I cannot access view1 here. but if the class was objective c I could.

    }
}
```

I can access super class properties, but when I define it as instance variable I cannot access it

I even changed view1 to protected variable, but I still cannot refer to it

Comment: can you add code how you are doing so it will be easy to check what is wrong.

Comment: You have to add the code for us to help you out. Because most of the issues are caused due to missing something really small but very important part which end up causing the issue in the first place.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemBeigh MoinuddinGirach Thanks, I edited it

Answer (score 4):

Only Objective C properties are exported to Swift. Instance variables are invisible to Swift.

See: [Accessing Objective-c base class's instance variables from a Swift class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082999/accessing-objective-c-base-classs-instance-variables-from-a-swift-class)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to some good ideas provided in the thread quoted by @Gunter, here is another approach.  You can create a category on `ObjectivecViewController` and add a property backed by the `view1` instance variable via custom accessor methods.

In `ObjectivecViewController+ViewProperty.h`:

```
#import "ObjectivecViewController.h"

@interface ObjectivecViewController (ViewProperty)

@property UIView * view1; // I would use a different name for the property
                          // to avoid confusion, though...
// Getter and setter
-(UIView*)view1;
-(void)setView1:(UIView * _Nonnull)view_1;

@end
```

Its implementation:

```
#import "ObjectivecViewController+ViewProperty.h"

@implementation ObjectivecViewController (ViewProperty)

-(UIView*)view1 {
    return self->view1;
}

-(void)setView1:(UIView * _Nonnull)view_1 {
    self->view1 = view_1;
}

@end
```

Then import `ObjectivecViewController+ViewProperty.h` in your bridging header.  Now your Swift class should be able to use the inherited `view1` property backed by the instance variable of the same name in the Objective-C superclass (again, I'd use different names for the property and the instance variable...).

Since you appear to be able to modify `ObjectivecViewController`'s source, you could just add the property there instead of in a category.

Hope this helps.  Or are you trying to avoid using a property to hide the view from outside code or for some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can access it using the variable name with ValueForKey

self.valueForKey("variableName")

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest you remove the `IBOutlet UIView *view1;` from the `.m` file
>   and declare a `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;` in
>   your `.h` file instead.

You should really declare your `UIView *view1;` in the `ObjectivecViewController` header file as a property to be able to access it from the child view controller. It won't be private anymore but it will work.

Accessing Objective-C private properties from a parent has always been an issue even when you inherit an objc class from another objc class.